# java mysql transaction deadlock

Tags: java, mysql, innodb, deadlock

I have a scenario like this (semi-pseudocode)

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
   SELECT cash FROM bank_1 WHERE user = 1;


   long money = rs.getLong("cash")
   ... if money >= the amount we want then...

   UPDATE bank_1 SET cash=cash-money WHERE user = 1;
   UPDATE bank_2 SET cash=cash+money WHERE user = 2;

   con.commit();

} catch(Exception e1) { 
   con.rollBack(); 
} finally { 
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
    try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

then I have to do the opposite in another program concurrently to transfer from the second bank to the first one, so
how do I avoid deadlock in this situation?

Comment: Try close `rs` before `UPDATE`.

Comment: and what about the updates which are also switching each other ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `FOR UPDATE` on the end of any `SELECTs` in the transaction.

```
SELECT cash FROM bank_1 WHERE user = 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

This locks the row(s) mentioned there so that other connections will not mess with the row before this transaction is finished.

(There are cases where `FOR UPDATE` is not needed, but that's a longer discussion.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a pattern like:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE bank_1 SET cash=cash - $money WHERE user = 1 AND cash >= $money

if rows affected > 0
   UPDATE bank_2 SET cash=cash + $money WHERE user = 2
   COMMIT
else
   ROLLBACK
```

Also having each bank in its own table make it harder to write queries. Consider a single table with a `bank_id`.

Comment: and what if I need to know first all information inside the transaction. If user 1 exists in bank_1 and how much money he has and secondly if he has the amount of money so that I can show him these information and finally transfer the money and know that transaction completed succesfully ?

Comment: I can't take into account uncited requirements. I did assume before you started that there was come concept of validating user 1 & 2 exist. The "if" condition is an application code, so rows affected > 0 indicated the transfer was successful.